# Name columns on store procedure informix 7.x

Tags: c#, nhibernate, informix

I have a store procedure on informix 7.x, this store procedure is called on Nhibernate using CreateSQLQuery method.

The problem is all columns retrieved by store procedure have the same name "expresion" so that when store procedure is called on NHibernate is not possible map these columns to an entity.

Is possible set an alias to columns on store procedure? or is possible rename colums on NHibernate?

Store Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ConFactPag
(
    paramCia            CHAR(2),
    paramPla            CHAR(2),    
    paramFechaInicial   DATE,
    paramFechaFinal     DATE    
)

RETURNING 
INT, 
CHAR(4), 
CHAR(10), 
CHAR(100),
CHAR(15), 
CHAR(15),
CHAR(100);

DEFINE v_folio      INT;
DEFINE v_serie      CHAR(4);
DEFINE v_fecha      CHAR(10);
DEFINE v_cliente    CHAR(110);
DEFINE v_importe    CHAR(15);
DEFINE v_saldo      CHAR(15);
DEFINE v_pago       CHAR(110);


FOREACH cFacturas FOR
    SELECT  f.fol_fac as v_folio, 
            f.ser_fac as v_serie, 
            TO_CHAR(f.fec_fac,'%d-%m-%Y'),
            CASE 
            WHEN TRIM(c.razsoc_cte) <> '' THEN
            TRIM(c.razsoc_cte) 
            ELSE 
            CASE    
            WHEN c.ali_cte <> '' THEN
                 TRIM(C.ali_cte) || ', ' 
              ELSE
                 '' 
           END || trim(c.nom_cte) || ' ' || TRIM(c.ape_cte) 
        END AS ncom_cte,
        LPAD(f.impt_fac,6,'0')
INTO    v_folio,
        v_serie,
        v_fecha,
        v_cliente,
        v_importe
FROM    factura f,
        cliente c
WHERE   f.numcte_fac = c.num_cte
        and f.tpa_fac = 'C'
        and f.cia_fac = paramCia
        and f.pla_fac = paramPla
        and f.fec_fac >= paramFechaInicial  
        and f.fec_fac <= paramFechaFinal
        --and f.fol_fac = 534896    

SELECT  SUM(sal_doc)
INTO    v_saldo
FROM    doctos
WHERE   ffac_doc = v_folio and sfac_doc = v_serie and tip_doc = '01';
LET v_pago = '';
IF v_saldo = 0 THEN
    SELECT  ser_pfac || ' ' || fol_pfac || ' ' || fec_pfac || ' ' || 
    imp_pfac
    INTO    v_pago
    FROM    pago_fac
    WHERE   ffac_pfac = v_folio and sfac_pfac = v_serie and numpag_pfac = 1;
END IF;

RETURN  v_folio,
        v_serie,
        v_fecha,
        v_cliente,
        v_importe,  
        LPAD(v_saldo,6,'0'),
        v_pago          
WITH RESUME;
END FOREACH;  
END PROCEDURE;
```

C#:

```
var listBills = this.facturaRepository.Session.CreateSQLQuery("EXECUTE PROCEDURE ConFactPag('15','02','2018-06-07','2018-06-07');").List();
```

Comment: See also [Renombrar columns procedimiento almacenado Informix 7.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189004/renombrar-columns-procedimiento-almacenado-inofrmix-7-x) on Spanish Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Informix Dynamic Server version 7 has been out of support for many years and you should consider upgrading to a supported version. The current versions are 11.70 and 12.10.

In the later versions of IDS it is possible to name the returned parameters of a stored procedure or function using the "AS " syntax for each value in the RETURNING clause. Using your example above this could be written as:

```
RETURNING 
INT AS folio, 
CHAR(4) AS serie, 
CHAR(10) AS fecha, 
CHAR(100) AS cliente,
CHAR(15) AS importe, 
CHAR(15) AS saldo,
CHAR(100) AS pago;
```

However I don't believe this feature is available in IDS version 7.

Comment: you right, it is possible to name the returned parameters in version 9 o later not in version 7, i think the unique option it is there something in NHibernate to name the returned parameters while get them